# What does "SMS Messaging Account" mean in Hangouts?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sms, google-account, privacy, google-hangouts

I'm using Nexus 5. In my Hangouts settings, I noticed that the setting called "Default SMS Messaging Account" was set to my email address with my full name (And can alternatively be changed to "SMS" instead, which hides previous chats)

Does this mean that I've been broadcasting my full name and email address to everyone I sent "SMSes" to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a weird and confusing design decision in my opinion.

To answer your question : No. Your full name and email address is only 
linked to your Google account and is only used for your Hangout chat.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide sources, or is this just a hunch? If this meta-info is transmitted, it may or may not show up in all messaging apps.

Comment: I do not have a source but I am sure about that.  The MAP protocol (used for SMS) does not even allow such thing. Jakar provided a good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8479310/3265284). ;)

Comment: So what is the difference?